# How can i fix this with threading or multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

So in short im making a python game using Tkinter for some GUI, Thats not the problem.
when im running the code its freesing for 10 second. tell me how i can fix this using threading.

sorry i cant write a question properly

```
def timepas():
    global time0
    global money
    global total_money
    global Invests
    global Invests_money
    global stopInvest
    global countlocal
    while stopInvest:
        countlocal = countlocal + 1
        Invests_money = Invests * 2
        money = money + Invests_money
        print(money)
        time.sleep(1)
        if countlocal == count:
            stopInvest = False
        continue



def work_money():
    global money
    money += 1


def BankAcc():
    global money
    messagebox.showinfo("Your Bank Account", "You have $:" + str(total_money))


def Inves():
    global Invests
    global money
    if money >= 10:
        Invests = Invests + 1
        money = money - 10


def stop_investing():
    global count
    global countlocal
    global total_money
    global money

    count = 10
    countlocal
    total_money = total_money + money
```

Comment: You dont need multithreading really, just stop usin sleep and just store a datetime and see if 10 seconds have elapsed before doing another action

Comment: If you didnt get enough information go to my github: https://github.com/azAZ09sdjk/python                                                                                ill see your answers tommorow its 1:30 nearly

Comment: You should wait to post your questions till a time you are able to respond to comments

Comment: How im new??? new to python to :c